# Python syntax error for

Tags: python, syntax-error

It is a python code.
`return runs = runs + l[key]['runs']['total']` .
 And it is showing this error:

```
return runs = runs + l[key]['runs']['total']
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
return runs + l[key]['runs']['total']
```

You can't do variable assignment and returning on the same line